# Javascript to Select Multiple options

Tags: javascript, forms, html-select

I have a form with a select box that allows multiple options. After a user saves these options, it stores them in a database table.

I can then read this database table to get the options they chose one again. I need to be able to grab this data from the database, put it into an array, then have the options in that select box to be pre-selected when they go to "Edit" their options.

Reading the data into an array is fine, and I know how to make a single option selected within a select box, however I'm not sure how to handle multiple options being selected in javascript.

Can someone help me figure out the javascript required to do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A pure javascript solution

```
<select id="choice" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">

var optionsToSelect = ['One', 'three'];
var select = document.getElementById( 'choice' );

for ( var i = 0, l = select.options.length, o; i < l; i++ )
{
  o = select.options[i];
  if ( optionsToSelect.indexOf( o.text ) != -1 )
  {
    o.selected = true;
  }
}

</script>
```

Although I agree this should be done server-side.

Comment: This is close, however the values stored are not the "index" of the options, they are the values of the options.

Comment: It's worth noting `Array.prototoype.indexOf` wasn't available in IE until version 9.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use it with  o.value instead of o.text but it works well

Comment: Hi could you explain your loop a little more I don't quite get it

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle please, I think I do the same but it won't work

Answer (score 5):

This type of thing should be done server-side, so as to limit the amount of resources used on the client for such trivial tasks. That being said, if you were to do it on the front-end, I would encourage you to consider using something like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) to keep the code clean and concise:

```
var values = ["Red", "Green"],
    colors = document.getElementById("colors");

_.each(colors.options, function (option) {
    option.selected = ~_.indexOf(values, option.text);
});
```

If you're using jQuery, it could be even more terse:

```
var values = ["Red", "Green"];

$("#colors option").prop("selected", function () {
    return ~$.inArray(this.text, values);
});
```

If you were to do this without a tool like underscore.js or jQuery, you would have a bit more to write, and may find it to be a bit more complicated:

```
var color, i, j,
    values = ["Red", "Green"],
    options = document.getElementById("colors").options;

for ( i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0, color = values[i]; j < options.length; j++ ) {
        options[j].selected = options[j].selected || color === options[j].text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have the select form, I was looking more for a javascript solution to the auto select. Every other part of the form uses javascript, I'm just not sure how to select multiple options with the javascript code.

Comment: Doing it server-side makes more sense, and you will still end up generating an array server-side for the client-side code.

Comment: Server side does make more sense, but I don't want to redo everything thats already done. The previous developer used all javascript, so I'm just going to stick with it for this.

Comment: The JS here can be simplified, and there's a bug - the HTML values are capitalized while the chosen variable is not, meaning this code won't select anything. Fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/RZT72/

Comment: @ChrisMoschini This answer is many years old, but I'm happy to brought it to the surface again so I could refresh its content. Nice solution as well, though you can make it even shorter :) See my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You can get access to the options array of a selected object by going `document.getElementById("cars").options` where 'cars' is the select object.

Once you have that you can call `option[i].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');` to select an option.

I agree with every one else that you are better off doing this server side though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function loopSelected()
{
  var txtSelectedValuesObj = document.getElementById('txtSelectedValues');
  var selectedArray = new Array();
  var selObj = document.getElementById('selSeaShells');
  var i;
  var count = 0;
  for (i=0; i<selObj.options.length; i++) {
    if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
      selectedArray[count] = selObj.options[i].value;
      count++;
    }
  }
  txtSelectedValuesObj.value = selectedArray;
}
function openInNewWindow(frm)
{
  // open a blank window
  var aWindow = window.open('', 'Tutorial004NewWindow',
   'scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,width=400,height=400');

  // set the target to the blank window
  frm.target = 'Tutorial004NewWindow';

  // submit
  frm.submit();
}
//-->
</script>
The HTML
<form action="tutorial004_nw.html" method="get">
  <table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="openInNewWindow(this.form);" />
      <input type="button" value="Loop Selected" onclick="loopSelected();" />
      <br />
      <select name="selSea" id="selSeaShells" size="5" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="val0" selected>sea zero</option>
        <option value="val1">sea one</option>
        <option value="val2">sea two</option>
        <option value="val3">sea three</option>
        <option value="val4">sea four</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
      <input type="text" id="txtSelectedValues" />
      selected array
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Peter Baley answer, I created a more generic function:

```
   @objectId: HTML object ID
   @values: can be a string or an array. String is less "secure" (should not contain repeated value).
   function checkMultiValues(objectId, values){
        selectMultiObject=document.getElementById(objectId);
        for ( var i = 0, l = selectMultiObject.options.length, o; i < l; i++ )
        {
          o = selectMultiObject.options[i];
          if ( values.indexOf( o.value ) != -1 )
          {
            o.selected = true;
          } else {
            o.selected = false;
          }
        }
    }
```

Example: `checkMultiValues('thisMultiHTMLObject','a,b,c,d');`

Comment: `o.selected = (values.indexOf (o.value) != -1)` will make the `if`-block obsolete.