# How do I programatically select an HTML option using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have option menu like this:

```
<form name="AddAndEdit">
   <select name="list" id="personlist">
      <option value="11">Person1</option>
      <option value="27">Person2</option>
      <option value="17">Person3</option>
      <option value="10">Person4</option>
      <option value="7">Person5</option>
      <option value="32">Person6</option>
      <option value="18">Person7</option>
      <option value="29">Person8</option>
      <option value="28">Person9</option>
      <option value="34">Person10</option>
      <option value="12">Person11</option>
      <option value="19">Person12</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

And now I want to change the selected option by using an href. For example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"
  onclick="document.getElementById('personlist').getElementsByTagName('option')[11].selected = 'selected';">change</a>
```

But I want to select the option with `value=11 (Person1)`, not `Person12`.

How do I change this code?

Answer (score 331, accepted):

Change

```
document.getElementById('personlist').getElementsByTagName('option')[11].selected = 'selected'
```

to

```
document.getElementById('personlist').value=Person_ID;
```

Comment: how does this work with multiple values? For example: `document.getElementById('personlist').value=id1,id2` will not work, how to manage that?

Comment: @utdev here is a solution for multiple selecting http://stackoverflow.com/a/1296068/1251563
tip: you need to use a loop

Comment: So I can't do something like `.value = id1, id2` or `.value = [array]` ?

Comment: @utdev unfortunately no... You need to use a loop

Comment: Also you can get value through select options without setting the class like `var id = document.getElementById('personlist').value`. I used in different answer, thanks anyway!

Comment: Warning: If your select box have options that aren't empty but the value in JS is empty, to set it with `.value = '';` will make your select box empty which is not exists.

Answer (score 75):

Tools as pure JavaScript code for handling Selectbox:

***Graphical Understanding:***

> ***Image - A***

[image]

---

> ***Image - B***

[image]

---

> ***Image - C***

[image]

**Updated - 25-June-2019 | [Fiddler DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/neerajsinghsonu/EpMcd/)**

**JavaScript Code:**

```
/**
 * Empty Select Box
 * @param eid Element ID
 * @param value text
 * @param text text
 * @author Neeraj.Singh
 */
function emptySelectBoxById(eid, value, text) {
    document.getElementById(eid).innerHTML = "<option value='" + value + "'>" + text + "</option>";
}


/**
 * Reset Select Box
 * @param eid Element ID
 */

function resetSelectBoxById(eid) {
    document.getElementById(eid).options[0].selected = 'selected';
}


/**
 * Set Select Box Selection By Index
 * @param eid Element ID
 * @param eindx Element Index
 */

function setSelectBoxByIndex(eid, eindx) {
    document.getElementById(eid).getElementsByTagName('option')[eindx].selected = 'selected';
    //or
    document.getElementById(eid).options[eindx].selected = 'selected';
}


/**
 * Set Select Box Selection By Value
 * @param eid Element ID
 * @param eval Element Index
 */
function setSelectBoxByValue(eid, eval) {
    document.getElementById(eid).value = eval;
}


/**
 * Set Select Box Selection By Text
 * @param eid Element ID
 * @param eval Element Index
 */
function setSelectBoxByText(eid, etxt) {
    var eid = document.getElementById(eid);
    for (var i = 0; i < eid.options.length; ++i) {
        if (eid.options[i].text === etxt)
            eid.options[i].selected = true;
    }
}


/**
 * Get Select Box Text By ID
 * @param eid Element ID
 * @return string
 */

function getSelectBoxText(eid) {
    return document.getElementById(eid).options[document.getElementById(eid).selectedIndex].text;
}


/**
 * Get Select Box Value By ID
 * @param eid Element ID
 * @return string
 */

function getSelectBoxValue(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).options[document.getElementById(id).selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Comment: Great example on how to interact with a select with pure javascript!

Comment: Link to "Fiddler Demo" now results in 404/Page Not Found :-(

Comment: The question is "How do I change an HTML selected option using JavaScript?". You just copy/paste a piece of code without answering nothing.

Answer (score 59):

```
mySelect.value = myValue;
```

Where `mySelect` is your selection box, and `myValue` is the value you want to change it to.

Comment: Why didn't everyone vote this, is this a new feature? I only need to support recent browsers though so going with this anyhow.

Comment: I always had the notion that you couldn't do this, so I just kinda ignored it. But when I saw this answer, I tried it, and lo and behold, it works just like inputs. This has to be the right answer. +1

Comment: `document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "myValue"` worked for me

Comment: Amazing post, I didn't realise the solution was so simple.

Answer (score 33):

I believe that the blog post *[JavaScript Beginners – Select a dropdown option by value](http://www.imranulhoque.com/javascript/javascript-beginners-select-a-dropdown-option-by-value/)* might help you.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="selectItemByValue(document.getElementById('personlist'),11)">change</a>

function selectItemByValue(elmnt, value){

  for(var i=0; i < elmnt.options.length; i++)
  {
    if(elmnt.options[i].value === value) {
      elmnt.selectedIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 30):

You could also change select.options.selectedIndex DOM attribute like this:

```js
function selectOption(index){ 
  document.getElementById("select_id").options.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

```html
<p>
<select id="select_id">
  <option selected>first option</option>
  <option>second option</option>
  <option>third option</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
  <button onclick="selectOption(0);">Select first option</button>
  <button onclick="selectOption(1);">Select second option</button>
  <button onclick="selectOption(2);">Select third option</button>
</p>
```

Comment: What are you using for `index`? An integer between 0 and 2?

Answer (score 6):

If you are adding the option with javascript

```
function AddNewOption(userRoutes, text, id) 
{
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = text;
    option.value = id;
    option.selected = "selected";
    userdRoutes.add(option);
}
```

Comment: I think the question was “How do I change an HTML selected option using JavaScript?”

Answer (score 5):

You can use JQuery also

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#personlist').val("10");
}
```

Comment: Or, without query, saving a whole bunch of unnecessary overhead, `document.querySelector('#personlist').value=10;` .

Comment: This question is NOT about JQuery.

Answer (score 4):

Your own answer technically wasn't incorrect, but you got the index wrong since indexes start at 0, not 1. That's why you got the wrong selection.

```
document.getElementById('personlist').getElementsByTagName('option')[**10**].selected = 'selected';
```

Also, your answer is actually a good one for  cases where the tags aren't entirely English or numeric.

If they use, for example, Asian characters, the other solutions telling you to use .value() may not always function and will just not do anything. Selecting by tag is a good way to ignore the actual text and select by the element itself.

Answer (score 3):

An array Index will start from 0. If you want value=11 (Person1), you will get it with position `getElementsByTagName('option')[10].selected`.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old post, but if anyone is still looking for solution to this kind of problem, here is what I came up with:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    document.forms['AddAndEdit'].elements['list'].value = 11;
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Option Index count starts from 0. That means first option will be indexed at 0.

```js
document.querySelector(".add__btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var index = 1; /*change option value here*/  document.querySelector(".add__type").options.selectedIndex = index;
  document.querySelector(".add__description").value = "Option Index";
  document.querySelector(".add__value").value = index;
});
```

```html
<html>
    <div class="add__container">
         <select class="add__type">
            <option value="inc" selected>+</option>
            <option value="exp">-</option>
         </select>
         <input type="text" class="add__description" placeholder="Add description">
         <input type="number" class="add__value" placeholder="Value">
         <button class="add__btn"> Submit </button>
</div>

<h4> Default Option Value will be selected after pressing Submit </h4>
```

Answer (score -1):

Jquery solution,

```
$('select').prop('selectedIndex', 1);
```