# Select dropdown value equal to php variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to select the value, of the dropdown called "Type", that's equal to the value of the PHP variable called "$Type" by using Javascript. I know there is a "selectindex" funciton in JS but "$Type" doesn't contain numbers only text.

I tried to use a loop I found on this site, but that didn't work for me.

PHP:

```
while(list($ArtikelID, $Type) = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $arid = $ArtikelID;
  $te = $Type;
}
```

HTML + JS:

```
<form name="send" method="post" action="editartticlesdef.php">
    articlenumber: </br>
    <input readonly="readonly" name="ArticleID" value=<?php echo $arid ?>></br>
    Type: </br>
    <select name="Type" id="Type">
        <option value="Article">Article</option>
        <option value="Code">Code</option>
        <option value="News">News</option>
        <option value="Project">Project</option>
    </select></br>
<script>
    window.onload = function SelectType() 
    {
        var sel = document.getElementById('Type');
        var val = document.getElementById('<?php echo $te; ?>');
        for(var i = 0, j = sel.options.length; i < j; ++i) 
        {
            if(sel.options[i].innerHTML === val) 
            {
               sel.selectedIndex = i;
               break;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

</form>
```

I'm not using Ajax or Jquery, so that's why I tried to use the loop. But it doesn't work for some reason. The dropdown still selects the first option on default when loaded.

Comment: You don't need javascript to show value selected. You can write condition to set attribute `selected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way, using PHP.

```
<?php
$listArticle = array(
                'Article',
                'Code',
                'News',
                'Project'
            );
?>
<select name="Type" id="Type">
    <?php    
    foreach($listArticle as $article)
    {
        $selected = '';
        if($article == $te)
        {
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';
        }

        echo '<option '.$selected.'>'.$article.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select></br>
```

Comment: This works! I had to edit a little bit though, you forgot a ; and your if loop should been "$te" instead of "$Type". So I edited your answer but it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, thanks for correcting it. I just approved your modifications.

Answer (score 0):

The `index` referred to in `selectedIndex` for a select menu is an integer referring to the option item index in the menu - not the value contained therein.

For the javascript, try:

```
 if( sel.options[ sel.options.selectedIndex ].value === val ){
      sel.selectedIndex = i;
      break;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't work either, it still will show the very first option of the dropdown when it loads.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the for loop at all, instead do (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911526/how-to-change-html-selected-option-using-javascript)):

```
window.onload = function SelectType() 
    {
        var sel = document.getElementById('Type');
        var val = document.getElementById('<?php echo $te; ?>');
        sel.value = val;
    }
```

This require the val to be presented in the options.

Comment: I tried your code, it causes my dropdown to become blank.

Comment: Well, as I said, the options must have one value the same as val. otherwise it would cause the select to become blank