# Set an option value as selected

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to load a select box where in the user's selected value will automatically appear.

I am receiving a Json data from the server with the user info.
sample of data is: `{"color":"red"}`

In my html code I have select option like this:

```
<select id="input_user" class="selectinput" disabled="true">
<option value="n/a"> n/a </option>
<option value="red"> red </option> 
<option value="green"> green </option>
<option value="yellow"> yellow </option>
<option value="blue"> blue </option>
<option value="white"> white </option>
</select> //this will only show "n/a" as default
```

I tried this code to make the red value as default but not working.

```
var user_color= data[2].color; // this was from the json data
document.getElementById('input_user').selectedIndex = user_color;
```

Any help?

Comment: Is `data` an array? Have you parsed the JSON came from the server?

Comment: check [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uos8hpL2/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you've tagged this question with jQuery you can just set the `val()` on the `select` directly:

```js
var user_color = 'red'; //data[2].color;
$('#input_user').val(user_color);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="input_user" class="selectinput" disabled="true">
  <option value="n/a">n/a</option>
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
  <option value="white">white</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think Rory's answer is correct. you are setting your select index, instead of updating value.

Comment: now he can downvote as much as he likes :D. This answer is correct and I can't imagine this is the first time it was asked and answered correctly.

Comment: what is the different with this? document.getElementById('input_user').value = user_color ;

Comment: @c.k: the difference is, that the answer uses jQuery and your suggestion is pure JavaScript. If you want a pure JavaScript answer, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911526/how-to-change-html-selected-option-using-javascript

Comment: Thanks for the help @RoryMcCrossan!

Comment: Glad to help. Also note that I gave a jQuery answer as you tagged the question with jQuery only.

Answer (score 4):

after much research, I finally went back to see the jQuery documentation that gave me the right answer :

1 / Delete all the attributes of  tags that are already with the 'selected' attribute

```
function remove_selected(){
  $("select option").removeAttr('selected');
}
```

2 / I use the prop() function of jQuery to assign the 'selected' attribute to the desired  tag

```
// USE THE FUNCTION TO REMOVE ALL ATTRIBUTES ALREADY SELECTED  
remove_selected();

// Set the tag <option> attribute to 'selected'
$('select option[value="ThatYouWant"]').prop({defaultSelected: true});
```

In HTML this gives :

```
<select>
  <option value="something">Something</option>
  <option value="ThatYouWant" selected>That you want</option>
  <option value="OtherValue">Other value</option>
</select>
```

It is clean and without burrs, thank you for your feedback and corrections, approve if you find this solution correct. Sincerely, Raf.

Source : https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: +1 for this alternative; unlike the accepted answer, this modifies the html. It helped me when modifying a dom node before further duplication.

Comment: Thank you for the return, indeed, I have previously observed changes on the DOM but not on the HTML, it looks like a hack, but hey what can we do ...

Answer (score 0):

More easy way to do it is as follows:

```
$("#input_user").val("red").trigger("change");
```

Just pass the value in val() which you want to be as selected value.