# jQuery - apply "selected" to option of specific value

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how do I apply "selected" to option value C?

```
<select id="letters">
    <option value="A">A<option>
    <option value="B">B<option>
    <option value="C">C<option>
    <option value="D">D<option>
</select>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680075/set-selected-option-of-select-box , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497852/set-an-option-value-as-selected , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280499/jquery-set-select-index , and others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.9, jQuery has updated changed this functionality.

The "selected" state of an option is actually a property, therefore jQuery has changed this to use the `.prop()` method.

```
$('#letters option[value=C]').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to do something like this

```
$('#yourdropddownid').val('C');
```

or do something like this

```
 $('#yourdropddownid').value = 'C';
```

For more information please view this post

[JQuery - how to select dropdown item based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743975/jquery-how-to-select-dropdown-item-based-on-value)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function(){
 $('#letters').val('C');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="letters">
    <option value="A">A<option>
    <option value="B">B<option>
    <option value="C">C<option>
    <option value="D">D<option>
</select>
```

Find the object and set the selected value :

```
$('#letters').val('C');
```

Check the working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/yvow5030/