# unable to simulate click event on <select> element with onchange function

Tags: javascript, typescript, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a project with a chrome plugin to manipulate a web site content and add some more functionalities.

I have a `<select>` element I want to manipulate:

```
<select id="thePage:form:pBlock:address:addressTypeSelectionDropdown" name="thePage:form:pBlock:address:addressTypeSelectionDropdown" size="1" onchange="onchangeOfPicklist();">    
    <option value="User Entry">User Entry</option>
    <option value="CustomerID">CustomerID</option>
    <option value="Closest to Customer">Closest to Customer</option>
    <option value="Location">Location</option>
    <option value="Customer's Address" selected="selected">Customer's Address</option>
</select>
```

I would like to change the select option in specific if conditions, but this doesn't seems to work whatever I do. So far I have tried almost everything, but it seems the onchange trigger is doing the magic, otherwise click simulations and trying to change options doesn't seem to work. So far I have tried different approaches, but they all seems not to trigger an option:

```
let customerAddress = labelAddress.parent().next().first().find("select");
customerAddress.children('[value="Closest to Customer"]').trigger("change");
```

and also :

```
customerAddress.children('[value="Closest to Customer"]').attr("selected", "selected");
customerAddress.children('[value="Closest to Customer"]').change();
```

and

```
customerAddress
.find('option:Closest to Customer')
.prop('selected',true)
.trigger('change');
```

and even simulating keypress:

```
let e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 13; // # enter
customerAddress.focus();
customerAddress.trigger(e);
```

Here I have no idea why the event is not being triggered.

I'm adding an event listener and the console doesn't indicate the event trigger:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
console.log("KeyPress: " + event.which);
});
```

or like this :

```
let e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 13; // # enter 
customerAddress.focus();
customerAddress.attr("size", 5);
customerAddress.children('[value="Closest to Customer"]').focus();
customerAddress.children('[value="Closest to Customer"]').trigger(e);
```

Please note that I'm working on the chrome plugin and I only can change the source code of this plugin and manipulate elements on the webpage, not able to change the source code of the webpage / scripts and functions.

My question is, is there a way to trigger the embedded onchange function in the `<select>` element?

https://jsfiddle.net/zlobul/sb8js1we/11/

Comment: in `let customerAddress = labelAddress.parent().next().first().find("select");`, what is `labelAddress` ?

Comment: `let labelAddress = $("label:contains('Address Type')");`
I'm properly getting the element if this is what you are wondering . I'm able to manipulate the size of the <select> element for example with `customerAddress.attr("size" , 5 ) ; `

Comment: Yep, I was wondering. :)

Comment: And where is your `label`? Can you try to make a working snippet of the problem with all the elements involved?

Comment: here is how it looks like : https://jsfiddle.net/zlobul/sb8js1we/3/

Comment: here - the event is not being triggered - https://jsfiddle.net/zlobul/sb8js1we/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here is what I did to make this working, similar to Michael.Lumley's answer :

```
let execFunct = function () {
    let script: HTMLScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "onchangeOfPicklist()";
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
    script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
}
```

once I change the dropdown I execute the execFunct().

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
let select = document.getElementById("thePage:form:pBlock:address:addressTypeSelectionDropdown")
select.addEventListener("change", (event)=>{
    console.log(event)
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    s.content = "onchangeofPicklist()"
    select.appendChild(s);
})
```

You need to intercept the change event using an event listener, and you should be able to call the existing change event handler (if necessary) from your new (extended) handler [by injecting a script into the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499994/access-window-variable-from-content-script).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvhfyadc/3/)

Comment: yes , but as I said onchangeOfPicklist() is not part of my code , so I'm getting an error : [ts] Property 'onchangeOfPicklist' does not exist on type 'Window'.

Comment: thanks , but this also doesnt seems to work , I have modified a little bit as using typescript :

Comment: `select.addEventListener("change", (event)=>{
                            console.log(event);
                            let s:any = document.createElement('script');
                            s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
                            s.content = "onchangeofPicklist()";
                            select.appendChild(s);
                        });
                        customerAddress.change();
                        customerAddress.val("Closest to Customer");`

Answer (score 1):

The change event is triggered at `select` element level not `option`, so :

```
let customerAddress = labelAddress.parent().next().first().find("select");
customerAddress.change();
```

should do the trick and trigger a `change` event for the select element. And if you want to set the value use val() :

```
customerAddress.val("Closest to Customer");
```

See [Set an option value as selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497852/set-an-option-value-as-selected)

Comment: this is only triggering the change of the value , but not triggering the change event . Doesn't work in my case ...

Comment: Look at doc : https://api.jquery.com/change/ - "Note: Changing the value of an input element using JavaScript, using .val() for example, won't fire the event.". Use customerAddress.val("Closest to Customer").change() to set value AND trigger a change event