# How to select option of select tag via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ecmascript-6

Below javascript to populate years, now need to select year that is posted from frontend.

e.g if year 1903 is sent the option with value 1903 should be selected.

```
var start = 1900;
var end = new Date().getFullYear();
var options = "";
var yearpost = "<?php echo $year ?>";
for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
  options += "<option "
  if (year == yearpost) {
    document.write('selected')
  }
  ">" + year + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = options;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change an HTML selected option using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911526/how-do-i-change-an-html-selected-option-using-javascript)

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`, ever. You'll want `options += "<option " + (year == yearpost ? 'selected' : '') + ">" + year + "</option>";` A much much better solution though is to simply call `document.getElementById("year").value = yearpost` at the end.

Comment: Quick fix: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/en56q83v/

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG for your prompt solution and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You wrongly wote `document.write` instead of `options +=` inside `if` block :

```js
var start = 1900;
var end = new Date().getFullYear();
var options = "";
var yearpost = "2011";
for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
  options += "<option ";
  if (year == parseInt(yearpost)) {
    options += ('selected')
  }
  options += ">" + year + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = options;
```

```html
<select id="year"></select>
```

Or you can simplify the `if` statement to this:
`options += '<option ' + (year == parseInt(yearpost) ? ' selected' : '') + '>' + year + '</option>';`

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly you want the option to be selected when it matches the year. The way you're doing it you are writing to the document, instead you should add it to the string you're creating. Inside your if statement try doing this instead : `option += "selected"`