# Are python-made dropdown menus editable in HTML / CSS?

Tags: python, html, css, web2py

So basically i created a dropdown menu using this method:

Controller:

```
        all_useroptions = []
        for opt in db().select(db.useroptions.ALL):
            all_useroptions.append(OPTION(opt.symbol, _value=opt.id))
        opt_sel = SELECT(*all_useroptions, _name='opt_id', value=request.vars.opt_id)
```

HTML:

```
 {{=opt_sel}}
```

Is it possible to edit the "dropdown" part of the menu? I can edit the "button" of my menu using CSS:

```
        #opt_id {
        color: rgb(105,105,105);
        padding: 10px 10px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 10px 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        min-width: 160px;
        }
```

But that only changes the button and not my menu. I would like to make the menu "prettier" by changing its shape, color and height and add some text between the options. Anybody knows how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your final HTML that is output to the page (inspect the page generated by your python script to find what it makes), you could add a custom js snippet to further modify the HTML, modifying elements dynamically based on what the initial code output.

```html
    ...template code above that contains yours {{=opt_sel}}...

    <!-- javascript snippet you add at bottom of page to change html above -->
    <script>
       document.querySelectorAll(".classOnABunchOfElementsMadeByOptSel > li").style.background = "red";
       document.querySelector("#secondElementMadeByOptSel").style.margin = "20px";

    </script>
```

see [How do I change an HTML selected option using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911526/how-do-i-change-an-html-selected-option-using-javascript)

and for a more basic primer on how to modify HTML with javascript:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just add the _class to the OPTION helper list of arguments:

```
all_useroptions = []
for opt in db().select(db.useroptions.ALL):
    all_useroptions.append(OPTION(opt.symbol, _value=opt.id, _class='prettier'))
opt_sel = SELECT(*all_useroptions, _name='opt_id', value=request.vars.opt_id)
```

And create a "pretier"css definition with your preferences

For more information, consult the web2py documentation for the HTML helpers:
    http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#HTML-helpers

```
    *Named arguments that start with an underscore are interpreted as HTML tag attributes (without the underscore)*
```