# How to select option in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code (HTML) :

```
<select name="size"    id="size">
```

Cat
Dog

How to get (“Dog’’) selected option in javaScript?

```
<select name="animal" id="animal">
```

Cat
Dog

and how to click button using javascript?

```
<fieldset id="add-remove-buttons">
```

My html is:

```html
<select name="size" id="size">
  <option value="72452">Cat</option>
  <option value="72453">Dog</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have the following code (HTML) :
<select name="size"    id="size">
<option value="72452">Cat</option>
<option value="72453">Dog</option></select>


How to get (“Dog’’) selected option in javaScript?

<select name="animal"    id="animal">
<option value="72452">Cat</option>
<option value="72453">Dog</option></select>

and how to click button using javascript?

<fieldset id="add-remove-buttons">
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="add " class="button">

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change an HTML selected option using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911526/how-do-i-change-an-html-selected-option-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the value of your option, you can just force it in the `value` field

```js
document.getElementById("size").value="72453"
```

```html
<select name="size" id="size">
  <option value="72452">Cat</option>
  <option value="72453">Dog</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I only know the text("dog") of my option.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your `<select>` tag by its id and save it in a variable using `getElementById()` method of a `document` object like this:

```
let selectSize = document.getElementById('size');
```

Then you can call the `selectSize.option` key which will return you an `HTMLOptionsCollection` object that has multiple useful properties such as `length`. You can then just call for the needed key in that object. For example, if i want to find Dog in your select field i'll do the following:

```
let selectSize = document.getElementById('size');
let keys = selectSize.options;

for (key of keys) {
    if (key.innerHTML === 'Dog') {
        console.log('Found a dog at index ', key.index, ' its value is ', key.value);
    }
}
```

Which will print out the following result:

```
Found a dog at index  1  its value is  72453
```

---

[More about Document object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)

[More about getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

[More about for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)