# I want to fill all these elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want all of the following boxes to be filled "excellent":

[image: Screenshot of modules table]

```js
let a = document.querySelectorAll('.select2-choice');
   a.forEach((e) => {console.log(e)})
   a.forEach((e) => {e.innerHTML = `   <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-410">-Excellent-</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
`})
```

I selected their class using `querySelectorAll` and changed the `innerHTML`. However, it only changes the pre-written text in the fields but doesn't select the actual options. I just want to fill them with any of their fields, and all at once.

Comment: It sounds like the webpage you're trying to manipulate uses the jQuery plugin 'select2' to make custom looking select boxes on the page. You probably want to do this https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911526/how-do-i-programatically-select-an-html-option-using-javascript

Comment: @rishi The post you've linked doesn't help, no select elements involved in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this and assign the value of the selected item :

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".class_name");
for (const input of inputs) {
  input.value = "some text";
}
```

Comment: I doubt that all elements should get the same value. Then it would make no sense to have multiple elements in the first place.

Comment: it was an example. He can can the input of each element according to his needs.