# How to change what is selected in a HTML select element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make select an element using Javascript in this HTML-select element

```
<div class="vb-fg-field-input ">
  <select class="slimselect required" name="tx_vbformgenerator_vb_formgenerator[Anrede]" tabindex="-1" data-ssid="ss-2638" style="display: none;" data-ddg-inputtype="unknown">
    <option value=" ">not specified</option>
    <option value="1">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="2">Mr.</option>
    <option value="5">Mx.</option>
  </select>
  <div class="ss-2638 ss-main slimselect required" style="">
    <div class="ss-single-selected">
      <span class="placeholder">not specified</span>
      <span class="ss-deselect ss-hide">x</span>
      <span class="ss-arrow">
        <span class="arrow-down"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="ss-content">
      <div class="ss-search ss-hide">
        <input readonly="" type="search" placeholder="Search" tabindex="0" aria-label="Search">
      </div>
      <div class="ss-list">
        <div class="ss-option ss-disabled ss-option-selected" data-id="84420967">not specified</div>
        <div class="ss-option" data-id="78147293">Mrs.</div>
        <div class="ss-option" data-id="65028532">Mr.</div>
        <div class="ss-option" data-id="13286904">Mx.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I read this question, [How do I programatically select an HTML option using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911526/how-do-i-programatically-select-an-html-option-using-javascript) , especially this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41969836/1802826 , but none of the suggested solutions seem to work for me.

I have tried this JS

```
document.getElementsByClassName('slimselect')[0].value = "Mr."
```

which returns

```
<- 'Mr.'
```

.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('slimselect')[0].querySelectorAll('option')[2].selected = "Mr."
```

which returns

```
<- 'Mr.'

document.getElementsByClassName('slimselect')[0].querySelector('option')[2]
```

which returns

```
<- Undefined
```

and multiple variations of these.

**How do I, using JavaScript (preferably a "oneliner"), change what is selected here, either based on index (1-4), the `value` attribute (1, 2, 5) or the element string (`not specified`, `Mrs.`, `Mr.` or `Mx.`)?**

Note that I want to do it from the browser console, because I will later on wrap in an AppleScript that controls a browser. I am not gonna use it in a webpage.

Comment: You are setting the value to match the label, for the option `"Mr."`, the value is `"2"`

Comment: Look at the `value`s of your `<option>`s.  Set the value of the select to one of those (like "2" for "Mr.").

Comment: `[elementReference].selected = true;` (for JS property approach). `[elementReference].setAttribute("selected", "selected")` (for HTML attribute approach).

Comment: [`selected` is a boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#selected)

Comment: Seems like you are using a third party control from the class names. You probably should be using its api to set the selected item and not the DOM.

Comment: @epascarello Not sure if your comment was in response to mine. If so, it is suggested to provide Boolean attributes with a value equal to the name of the attribute in cases where specifying a value is either required or makes the code more readable.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It was just a comment on OP using a random string. And in the end it does not matter since it is a 3rd party component and updating the select is meaningless when the script does not know a change was made. Classic onchange does not fire when JS sets the value.

Answer (score 1):

The control is a third party script so setting the value/index with just the DOM select is not going to notify the JavaScript something changed. JavaScript does not trigger events when you update the value/selectedIndex so you need to trigger events for it to pick up the change you made. You do that with `dispathEvent`.

```js
const sel = document.querySelector('.slimselect');
sel.selectedIndex = 2;
sel.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

or you use their api to set it

```js
const sel = document.querySelector('.slimselect');
sel.slim.setSelected(['2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `<option>` with the specified text, then set the `<select>` element's `selectedIndex`.

```js
const textToSelect = 'Mr.';
const select = document.querySelector('.slimselect');
select.selectedIndex = [...select.options].findIndex(o => o.text === textToSelect);
```

```html
<select class="slimselect required">
  <option value=" ">not specified</option>
  <option value="1">Mrs.</option>
  <option value="2">Mr.</option>
  <option value="5">Mx.</option>
</select>
```

If you already know the index of the option to choose, you can directly set it:

```js
document.querySelector('.slimselect').selectedIndex = 2;
```

If you know the value of the option to choose:

```js
document.querySelector('.slimselect').value = '2';
// value of <option> with text of "Mr."
```

Comment: I know the index or value I want to select so I tried with your last two suggestions - but the select element is not updated when I run these snippets in the console (and as a consequence, the form this select belongs to is not valid and can't be submitted). Do you know why?

Comment: @d-b Can you provide a [mre]? It works in the example snippet, so there must be something else affecting it.

Comment: It seems to be just a visual glitch, the form is accepted, despite that this select element still appears unselected.

Comment: @d-b With the SlimSelect library, you should call `.setSelected('value')` on the SlimSelect instance.

Comment: `<option value=" ">not specified</option>` should be: `<option value="">not specified</option>` otherwise the value of that option would be a space when selected.

Comment: It is not my web page. I script a browser to use this webpage, hence my question.