# Selecting multiple options with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use javascript on the form's load to pre-select some options. This is what I have.

```
    var mar=document.getElementById('region');
    var marketarray = '@marketlistdb@'.split("|");
    for( var l = 0; l < mar.options.length; l++ )
    {
        var o = mar.options[l];
        if ( marketarray.indexOf( o.text ) != -1 )
        {
            mar.selected = true;
        }
    }
```

But this will not select the elements in the select tag. I saw this solution elsewhere ([Javascript to Select Multiple options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295950/javascript-to-select-multiple-options)) I tried this solution, but it will not work for whatever reason. Does anyone see anything wrong that would cause this not to select?

We have placed alerts within the for loop and within the if statement to verify that we have true matches between the array and each individual option.

Comment: P.S this is written in the $document.ready section.

Comment: `var marketarray = '@marketlistdb@'.split("|");` - what?

Comment: It creates an array comprised of different markets resulting from a SQL query

Comment: If you put `console.log(marketarray)` right after that line, what is the result?

Comment: ["es-MX", "tr-TR", "de-CH"]

Comment: I believe you want `mar.options[l].selected = true`

Comment: We have verified during the loop that we are hitting true during the comparison for each of those results. The only thing that doesn't work is the mar.selected = true; portion

Comment: Try setting the actual `.selected` of the option, see my comment above.

Comment: Yeah, that was really dumb of me. in other words, it should be o.selected = true; Even so, it's not selecting for us.

Comment: You have a combo-box? I.e. you have `multiple` attribute set in the `select`?

Comment: We have it set as a select type = multiple

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. multiple=multiple