# Programatically selecting multiple options from HTML select dropdown using JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript

I am developing a Web application. In my application, I am trying to select multiple options for the select dropdown using JavaScript.

This is my HTML

```
<select id="my-dropdown"
        name="select_locations"
        multiple="multiple"
        class="my-select-control">
        //options are here
</select>
```

This is my JavaScript

```
let dropDown = document.getElementById('my-dropdown');
dropDown.options[0].selected = true
dropDown.options[1].selected = true
```

But it is not selecting the options. How can I select multiple options?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript to Select Multiple options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295950/javascript-to-select-multiple-options)

Comment: also, your code works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/zmjfr5ek/

Comment: possibly your js executed before dom rendered

Comment: It works as expected. Must be something to do with the VueJs life cycle.